# Hide section in table of contents but show it in pdfbookmark

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

This question is linked to [another newer question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27170/7093).

For my PDF Bible I need the Bible-Chapter (section) to be hidden in the table of contents. The same Bible-Chapter (section) should however appear in the pdfbookmark which I am producing with the hyperref package, to enable navigation in the PDF file. I am able to produce either the one where everything is visible in both or the other where the Bible-chapters (sections) does not appear in either the bookmarks or table of contents.

How can I perhaps create pdfbookmarks that are not associated with the table of contents? Perhaps this would enable me to customise it some more.

This is what I can produce so far:
[image]
or
[image]

The only change between the two is this line:
\addtocounter{tocdepth}{-2}
changed to
\addtocounter{tocdepth}{-1}

Here is my code example:

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,pagesize=pdftex]{scrbook}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont{Cardo}

% definition of the page style with required headers
\newpagestyle{Biblestyle}{
  \setheadrule{.01pt}
  \sethead[\thepage][\chaptertitle][\toptitlemarks\thesection:\toptitlemarks\thesubsection---\bottitlemarks\thesection:\bottitlemarks\thesubsection]{\toptitlemarks\thesection:\toptitlemarks\thesubsection---\bottitlemarks\thesection:\bottitlemarks\thesubsection}{\chaptertitle}{\thepage}
}

% sets the marks to be used (section and subsection)
\setmarks{section}{subsection}

% sections and subsections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{}{\lettrine{\thesection}}{0em}{}[\vskip-1\baselineskip]
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\small\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{1em}{-1pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{1em}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\bfseries}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newlength\NumLen
\newlength\LinLen
% indents one line of text. Indentation= width of section number + 1em
\newcommand\IndOne{%
  \settowidth\NumLen{\thesection}
  \addtolength\NumLen{1em}
  \setlength\LinLen{\dimexpr\textwidth-\NumLen}%\the\NumLen\the\LinLen
  \parshape 2 \NumLen \LinLen 0pt \textwidth}
% indents two lines of text. Indentation= width of section number + 1em
\newcommand\IndTwo{%
  \settowidth\NumLen{\thesection}
  \addtolength\NumLen{1em}
  \setlength\LinLen{\dimexpr\textwidth-\NumLen}%\the\NumLen\the\LinLen
  \parshape 3 \NumLen \LinLen \NumLen \LinLen 0pt \textwidth}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
%   bookmarks=true,
    unicode=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor={black},
    linkcolor={black},
    urlcolor={black},
    pdffitwindow=true,
}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand*\cfttoctitlefont{\Large\hfill\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand*\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill}

\dottedcontents{chapter}[2.5em]{}{2.3em}{1pc}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
    % Titlepage
    \pdfbookmark[0]{Titlepage}{title}
    \title{}
    \subject{
        \vspace{3cm}
        \textbf{\Large{THE}\\\vspace{-0.3cm}
        \Huge{HOLY}\\\vspace{0.05cm}
        \Huge{BIBLE}}\\\vspace{0.5cm}
    \author{} \date{}
    }
    \maketitle

    % Dedication
    \newpage\pdfbookmark[1]{Extra Page}{ep}\vspace*{1cm}

\newpage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Table of Contents}{tofcontents}
\addtocounter{tocdepth}{-2}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{Biblestyle}
\renewcommand{\chaptertitle}{Genesis}
\begin{center}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Genesis}\noindent
%\pdfbookmark[0]{Genesis}{Genesis}
THE FIRST BOOK OF MOSES, CALLED\\
\vspace{0.15cm}\textbf{\Huge{GENESIS}}\vspace{0.00cm}\\
\end{center}
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{1}
\pdfbookmark[1]{1}{Genesis1}
\section{}

\IndTwo And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters. \stepcounter{subsection}
    \subsection{} And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.
    \subsection{} And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.
    \subsection{} And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament: and it was so.
    \subsection{} And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the morning were the second day.
    \subsection{} And God said, Let the waters under the heaven be gathered together unto one place, and let the dry land appear: and it was so.
    \subsection{} And God called the dry land Earth; and the gathering together of the waters called he Seas: and God saw that it was good.
    \subsection{} And God said, Let the earth bring forth grass, the herb yielding seed, and the fruit tree yielding fruit after his kind, whose seed is in itself, upon the earth: and it was so.
    \subsection{} And the earth brought forth grass, and herb yielding seed after his kind, and the tree yielding fruit, whose seed was in itself, after his kind: and God saw that it was good.
    \subsection{} And the evening and the morning were the third day.

%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{2}
\pdfbookmark[1]{2}{Genesis2}
\section{}
\IndTwo Thus the heavens and the earth were finished, and all the host of them.\stepcounter{subsection}
    \subsection{} \IndOne And on the seventh day God ended his work which he had made; and he rested on the seventh day from all his work which he had made.
    \subsection{} And God blessed the seventh day, and sanctified it: because that in it he had rested from all his work which God created and made.
    \subsection{} These are the generations of the heavens and of the earth when they were created, in the day that the \textsc{Lord} God made the earth and the heavens,
    \subsection{} And every plant of the field before it was in the earth, and every herb of the field before it grew: for the \textsc{Lord} God had not caused it to rain upon the earth, and there was not a man to till the ground.
    \subsection{} But there went up a mist from the earth, and watered the whole face of the ground.
    \subsection{} And the \textsc{Lord} God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul.
    \subsection{} And the \textsc{Lord} God planted a garden eastward in Eden; and there he put the man whom he had formed.
    \subsection{} And out of the ground made the \textsc{Lord} God to grow every tree that is pleasant to the sight, and good for food; the tree of life also in the midst of the garden, and the tree of knowledge of good and evil.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God took the man, and put him into the garden of Eden to dress it and to keep it.

%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{2}
\pdfbookmark[1]{3}{Genesis3}
\section{}
\IndTwo Thus the heavens and the earth were finished, and all the host of them.\stepcounter{subsection}
    \subsection{} \IndOne And on the seventh day God ended his work which he had made; and he rested on the seventh day from all his work which he had made.
    \subsection{} And God blessed the seventh day, and sanctified it: because that in it he had rested from all his work which God created and made.
    \subsection{} And the \textsc{Lord} God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul.
    \subsection{} And the \textsc{Lord} God planted a garden eastward in Eden; and there he put the man whom he had formed.
    \subsection{} And out of the ground made the \textsc{Lord} God to grow every tree that is pleasant to the sight, and good for food; the tree of life also in the midst of the garden, and the tree of knowledge of good and evil.
    \subsection{} And a river went out of Eden to water the garden; and from thence it was parted, and became into four heads.
    \subsection{} The name of the first is Pison: that is it which compasseth the whole land of Havilah, where there is gold;
    \subsection{} And the LORD God took the man, and put him into the garden of Eden to dress it and to keep it.

\clearpage
\renewcommand{\chaptertitle}{Exodus}
\begin{center}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Exodus}\noindent
THE FIRST BOOK OF MOSES, CALLED\\
\vspace{0.15cm}\textbf{\Huge{Exodus}}\vspace{0.00cm}\\
\end{center}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\pdfbookmark[1]{1}{Exodus1}
\section{}
\IndTwo Now the serpent was more subtil than any beast of the field which the LORD God had made. And he said unto the woman, Yea, hath God said, Ye shall not eat of every tree of the garden?
  \stepcounter{subsection}\subsection{} And the woman said unto the serpent, We may eat of the fruit of the trees of the garden:
    \subsection{} But of the fruit of the tree which is in the midst of the garden, God hath said, Ye shall not eat of it, neither shall ye touch it, lest ye die.
    \subsection{} And they heard the voice of the LORD God walking in the garden in the cool of the day: and Adam and his wife hid themselves from the presence of the LORD God amongst the trees of the garden.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God called unto Adam, and said unto him, Where art thou?
    \subsection{} And he said, I heard thy voice in the garden, and I was afraid, because I was naked; and I hid myself.
    \subsection{} And he said, Who told thee that thou wast naked? Hast thou eaten of the tree, whereof I commanded thee that thou shouldest not eat?
    \subsection{} And the man said, The woman whom thou gavest to be with me, she gave me of the tree, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the woman, What is this that thou hast done? And the woman said, The serpent beguiled me, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the serpent, Because thou hast done this, thou art cursed above all cattle, and above every beast of the field; upon thy belly shalt thou go, and dust shalt thou eat all the days of thy life:
    \subsection{} And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel.
    \subsection{} Unto the woman he said, I will greatly multiply thy sorrow and thy conception; in sorrow thou shalt bring forth children; and thy desire shall be to thy husband, and he shall rule over thee.

\pdfbookmark[1]{2}{Exodus2}
\section{}\IndTwo Now the serpent was more subtil than any beast of the field which the LORD God had made. And he said unto the woman, Yea, hath God said, Ye shall not eat of every tree of the garden?
  \stepcounter{subsection}\subsection{} And the woman said unto the serpent, We may eat of the fruit of the trees of the garden:
    \subsection{} But of the fruit of the tree which is in the midst of the garden, God hath said, Ye shall not eat of it, neither shall ye touch it, lest ye die.
    \subsection{} And the serpent said unto the woman, Ye shall not surely die:
    \subsection{} And the LORD God called unto Adam, and said unto him, Where art thou?
    \subsection{} And he said, I heard thy voice in the garden, and I was afraid, because I was naked; and I hid myself.
    \subsection{} And he said, Who told thee that thou wast naked? Hast thou eaten of the tree, whereof I commanded thee that thou shouldest not eat?
    \subsection{} And the man said, The woman whom thou gavest to be with me, she gave me of the tree, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the woman, What is this that thou hast done? And the woman said, The serpent beguiled me, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the serpent, Because thou hast done this, thou art cursed above all cattle, and above every beast of the field; upon thy belly shalt thou go, and dust shalt thou eat all the days of thy life:
    \subsection{} And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel.
    \subsection{} Unto the woman he said, I will greatly multiply thy sorrow and thy conception; in sorrow thou shalt bring forth children; and thy desire shall be to thy husband, and he shall rule over thee.

\pdfbookmark[1]{3}{Exodus3}
\section{}\IndTwo Now the serpent was more subtil than any beast of the field which the LORD God had made. And he said unto the woman, Yea, hath God said, Ye shall not eat of every tree of the garden?
  \stepcounter{subsection}\subsection{} And the woman said unto the serpent, We may eat of the fruit of the trees of the garden:
    \subsection{} But of the fruit of the tree which is in the midst of the garden, God hath said, Ye shall not eat of it, neither shall ye touch it, lest ye die.
    \subsection{} And the serpent said unto the woman, Ye shall not surely die:
    \subsection{} For God doth know that in the day ye eat thereof, then your eyes shall be opened, and ye shall be as gods, knowing good and evil.
        \subsection{} And when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, and that it was pleasant to the eyes, and a tree to be desired to make one wise, she took of the fruit thereof, and did eat, and gave also unto her husband with her; and he did eat.
        \subsection{} And the eyes of them both were opened, and they knew that they were naked; and they sewed fig leaves together, and made themselves aprons.
    \subsection{} And they heard the voice of the LORD God walking in the garden in the cool of the day: and Adam and his wife hid themselves from the presence of the LORD God amongst the trees of the garden.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God called unto Adam, and said unto him, Where art thou?
    \subsection{} And he said, I heard thy voice in the garden, and I was afraid, because I was naked; and I hid myself.
    \subsection{} And he said, Who told thee that thou wast naked? Hast thou eaten of the tree, whereof I commanded thee that thou shouldest not eat?
    \subsection{} And the man said, The woman whom thou gavest to be with me, she gave me of the tree, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the woman, What is this that thou hast done? And the woman said, The serpent beguiled me, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the serpent, Because thou hast done this, thou art cursed above all cattle, and above every beast of the field; upon thy belly shalt thou go, and dust shalt thou eat all the days of thy life:
    \subsection{} And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel.
    \subsection{} Unto the woman he said, I will greatly multiply thy sorrow and thy conception; in sorrow thou shalt bring forth children; and thy desire shall be to thy husband, and he shall rule over thee.

\clearpage
\renewcommand{\chaptertitle}{‏‏Leviticus}
\begin{center}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{‏‏Leviticus}\noindent
THE FIRST BOOK OF MOSES, CALLED\\
\vspace{0.15cm}\textbf{\Huge{‏‏Leviticus}}\vspace{0.00cm}\\
\end{center}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{}\IndTwo Now the serpent was more subtil than any beast of the field which the LORD God had made. And he said unto the woman, Yea, hath God said, Ye shall not eat of every tree of the garden?
  \stepcounter{subsection}\subsection{} And the woman said unto the serpent, We may eat of the fruit of the trees of the garden:
    \subsection{} But of the fruit of the tree which is in the midst of the garden, God hath said, Ye shall not eat of it, neither shall ye touch it, lest ye die.
    \subsection{} And the serpent said unto the woman, Ye shall not surely die:
    \subsection{} For God doth know that in the day ye eat thereof, then your eyes shall be opened, and ye shall be as gods, knowing good and evil.
        \subsection{} And when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, and that it was pleasant to the eyes, and a tree to be desired to make one wise, she took of the fruit thereof, and did eat, and gave also unto her husband with her; and he did eat.
        \subsection{} And the eyes of them both were opened, and they knew that they were naked; and they sewed fig leaves together, and made themselves aprons.
    \subsection{} And they heard the voice of the LORD God walking in the garden in the cool of the day: and Adam and his wife hid themselves from the presence of the LORD God amongst the trees of the garden.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God called unto Adam, and said unto him, Where art thou?
    \subsection{} And he said, I heard thy voice in the garden, and I was afraid, because I was naked; and I hid myself.
    \subsection{} And he said, Who told thee that thou wast naked? Hast thou eaten of the tree, whereof I commanded thee that thou shouldest not eat?
    \subsection{} And the man said, The woman whom thou gavest to be with me, she gave me of the tree, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the woman, What is this that thou hast done? And the woman said, The serpent beguiled me, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the serpent, Because thou hast done this, thou art cursed above all cattle, and above every beast of the field; upon thy belly shalt thou go, and dust shalt thou eat all the days of thy life:
    \subsection{} And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel.
    \subsection{} Unto the woman he said, I will greatly multiply thy sorrow and thy conception; in sorrow thou shalt bring forth children; and thy desire shall be to thy husband, and he shall rule over thee.

\section{}\IndTwo Now the serpent was more subtil than any beast of the field which the LORD God had made. And he said unto the woman, Yea, hath God said, Ye shall not eat of every tree of the garden?
  \stepcounter{subsection}\subsection{} And the woman said unto the serpent, We may eat of the fruit of the trees of the garden:
    \subsection{} But of the fruit of the tree which is in the midst of the garden, God hath said, Ye shall not eat of it, neither shall ye touch it, lest ye die.
    \subsection{} And the serpent said unto the woman, Ye shall not surely die:
    \subsection{} For God doth know that in the day ye eat thereof, then your eyes shall be opened, and ye shall be as gods, knowing good and evil.
        \subsection{} And when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, and that it was pleasant to the eyes, and a tree to be desired to make one wise, she took of the fruit thereof, and did eat, and gave also unto her husband with her; and he did eat.
        \subsection{} And the eyes of them both were opened, and they knew that they were naked; and they sewed fig leaves together, and made themselves aprons.
    \subsection{} And they heard the voice of the LORD God walking in the garden in the cool of the day: and Adam and his wife hid themselves from the presence of the LORD God amongst the trees of the garden.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God called unto Adam, and said unto him, Where art thou?
    \subsection{} And he said, I heard thy voice in the garden, and I was afraid, because I was naked; and I hid myself.
    \subsection{} And he said, Who told thee that thou wast naked? Hast thou eaten of the tree, whereof I commanded thee that thou shouldest not eat?
    \subsection{} And the man said, The woman whom thou gavest to be with me, she gave me of the tree, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the woman, What is this that thou hast done? And the woman said, The serpent beguiled me, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the serpent, Because thou hast done this, thou art cursed above all cattle, and above every beast of the field; upon thy belly shalt thou go, and dust shalt thou eat all the days of thy life:
    \subsection{} And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel.
    \subsection{} Unto the woman he said, I will greatly multiply thy sorrow and thy conception; in sorrow thou shalt bring forth children; and thy desire shall be to thy husband, and he shall rule over thee.

\section{}\IndTwo Now the serpent was more subtil than any beast of the field which the LORD God had made. And he said unto the woman, Yea, hath God said, Ye shall not eat of every tree of the garden?
  \stepcounter{subsection}\subsection{} And the woman said unto the serpent, We may eat of the fruit of the trees of the garden:
    \subsection{} But of the fruit of the tree which is in the midst of the garden, God hath said, Ye shall not eat of it, neither shall ye touch it, lest ye die.
    \subsection{} And the serpent said unto the woman, Ye shall not surely die:
    \subsection{} For God doth know that in the day ye eat thereof, then your eyes shall be opened, and ye shall be as gods, knowing good and evil.
        \subsection{} And when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, and that it was pleasant to the eyes, and a tree to be desired to make one wise, she took of the fruit thereof, and did eat, and gave also unto her husband with her; and he did eat.
        \subsection{} And the eyes of them both were opened, and they knew that they were naked; and they sewed fig leaves together, and made themselves aprons.
    \subsection{} And they heard the voice of the LORD God walking in the garden in the cool of the day: and Adam and his wife hid themselves from the presence of the LORD God amongst the trees of the garden.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God called unto Adam, and said unto him, Where art thou?
    \subsection{} And he said, I heard thy voice in the garden, and I was afraid, because I was naked; and I hid myself.
    \subsection{} And he said, Who told thee that thou wast naked? Hast thou eaten of the tree, whereof I commanded thee that thou shouldest not eat?
    \subsection{} And the man said, The woman whom thou gavest to be with me, she gave me of the tree, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the woman, What is this that thou hast done? And the woman said, The serpent beguiled me, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the serpent, Because thou hast done this, thou art cursed above all cattle, and above every beast of the field; upon thy belly shalt thou go, and dust shalt thou eat all the days of thy life:
    \subsection{} And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel.
    \subsection{} Unto the woman he said, I will greatly multiply thy sorrow and thy conception; in sorrow thou shalt bring forth children; and thy desire shall be to thy husband, and he shall rule over thee.

\section{}\IndTwo Now the serpent was more subtil than any beast of the field which the LORD God had made. And he said unto the woman, Yea, hath God said, Ye shall not eat of every tree of the garden?
  \stepcounter{subsection}\subsection{} And the woman said unto the serpent, We may eat of the fruit of the trees of the garden:
    \subsection{} But of the fruit of the tree which is in the midst of the garden, God hath said, Ye shall not eat of it, neither shall ye touch it, lest ye die.
    \subsection{} And the serpent said unto the woman, Ye shall not surely die:
    \subsection{} For God doth know that in the day ye eat thereof, then your eyes shall be opened, and ye shall be as gods, knowing good and evil.
        \subsection{} And when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, and that it was pleasant to the eyes, and a tree to be desired to make one wise, she took of the fruit thereof, and did eat, and gave also unto her husband with her; and he did eat.
        \subsection{} And the eyes of them both were opened, and they knew that they were naked; and they sewed fig leaves together, and made themselves aprons.
    \subsection{} And they heard the voice of the LORD God walking in the garden in the cool of the day: and Adam and his wife hid themselves from the presence of the LORD God amongst the trees of the garden.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God called unto Adam, and said unto him, Where art thou?
    \subsection{} And he said, I heard thy voice in the garden, and I was afraid, because I was naked; and I hid myself.
    \subsection{} And he said, Who told thee that thou wast naked? Hast thou eaten of the tree, whereof I commanded thee that thou shouldest not eat?
    \subsection{} And the man said, The woman whom thou gavest to be with me, she gave me of the tree, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the woman, What is this that thou hast done? And the woman said, The serpent beguiled me, and I did eat.
    \subsection{} And the LORD God said unto the serpent, Because thou hast done this, thou art cursed above all cattle, and above every beast of the field; upon thy belly shalt thou go, and dust shalt thou eat all the days of thy life:
    \subsection{} And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel.
    \subsection{} Unto the woman he said, I will greatly multiply thy sorrow and thy conception; in sorrow thou shalt bring forth children; and thy desire shall be to thy husband, and he shall rule over thee.

\section{}\IndTwo And Adam knew Eve his wife; and she conceived, and bare Cain, and said, I have gotten a man from the LORD.
    \stepcounter{subsection}\subsection{} And she again bare his brother Abel. And Abel was a keeper of sheep, but Cain was a tiller of the ground.
    \subsection{} And in process of time it came to pass, that Cain brought of the fruit of the ground an offering unto the LORD.
    \subsection{} And Abel, he also brought of the firstlings of his flock and of the fat thereof. And the LORD had respect unto Abel and to his offering:
    \subsection{} But unto Cain and to his offering he had not respect. And Cain was very wroth, and his countenance fell.
    \subsection{} And the LORD said unto Cain, Why art thou wroth? and why is thy countenance fallen?
    \subsection{} If thou doest well, shalt thou not be accepted? and if thou doest not well, sin lieth at the door. And unto thee shall be his desire, and thou shalt rule over him.
    \subsection{} And Cain talked with Abel his brother: and it came to pass, when they were in the field, that Cain rose up against Abel his brother, and slew him.
    \subsection{} And the LORD said unto Cain, Where is Abel thy brother? And he said, I know not: Am I my brother's keeper?
    \subsection{} And he said, What hast thou done? the voice of thy brother's blood crieth unto me from the ground.
    \subsection{} And now art thou cursed from the earth, which hath opened her mouth to receive thy brother's blood from thy hand;
    \subsection{} When thou tillest the ground, it shall not henceforth yield unto thee her strength; a fugitive and a vagabond shalt thou be in the earth.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `shorttoc` to typeset the table of contents. However, you would still need to have the full toc somewhere iirc (maybe in the end).

Comment: @Raphink: Thanks I will investigate shorttoc but the answer below is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=1}
```

Then, only chapters will appear in the table of contents whereas chapters and sections will appear in the PDF bookmarks.